# One polygon shapefile is not visible despite successful export with QGIS2WEB

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, polygon, export, qgis2web

In my application, all the layers including vector and raster layers successfully imported and web-hosted, but only one vector layer is not visible online, which is visible in desktop mode as well as on the legend too. even I have increased the preview feature limit also. What could be a problem?

Comment: A path / name issue ?

Comment: It is likely to be something in the style which qgis2web doesn't support. Can you upload the map somewhere and tell us the name of the layer which is not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved.  Since the database has layers from different sources, the CRS of one particular layer was not appropriate for web display. After reprojecting, the application is working perfectly now.